# Count Occurrences of Nested Objects w/ Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have this `Movie` model where I have `Actor` as a nested object:

```
@objcMembers class Movie: Object, Mappable {

    dynamic var _id: String? = nil
    dynamic var actors = List<Actor>()
    // more stuff

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
}
```

As I fetch my movies from the server, and add them to my Realm (using Alamofire -> ObjectMapper -> RealmSwift), how can I find the most represented `Actor` in these `Results<Movie>`?

i.e. Nicolas Cage casts in 30 movies of my entire Movies collection. He is the most represented actor.

How would I "count" the occurrences of Actor Nicolas Cage being a nested object of my Movies?

I'm already achieving that with plain Swift, but I was wondering if there was an elegant way to do this with Realm Swift.

Thanks in advance ✌

PS: sorry for the poor choice of actor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to rely on Realm's built in functionality and use an inverse relationship.

Just add the inverse relationship to your `Actor` model class. `actedIn` will contain a reference to all `Movie` objects, which contain the `Actor` instance in their `actors` property.

When looking for the actor with most movies, you just have to fetch all actors from your Realm, then use the built in `max(by:)` function to find the one, whose `actedIn` has the most elements.

```
@objcMembers class Actor: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    let actedIn = LinkingObjects(fromType: Movie.self, property: "actors")
}

@objcMembers class Movie: Object {
    dynamic var _id: String? = nil
    dynamic var actors = List<Actor>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "_id"
    }
}

//Generate test data
try! realm.write {
    let nicholasCage = Actor(value:["name":"Nicholas Cage"])
    let adamSandler = Actor(value:["name":"Adam Sandler"])
    let jessicaBiel = Actor(value:["name":"Jessica Biel"])
    let nicoleKidman = Actor(value:["name":"Nicole Kidman"])
    realm.add([nicholasCage,adamSandler,jessicaBiel,nicoleKidman])
    let firstMovie = Movie()
    firstMovie.actors.append(objectsIn: [nicholasCage,nicoleKidman])
    firstMovie._id = "first"
    let secondMovie = Movie()
    secondMovie.actors.append(objectsIn: [nicholasCage,adamSandler])
    secondMovie._id = "second"
    let thirdMovie = Movie()
    thirdMovie.actors.append(objectsIn: [nicholasCage,nicoleKidman,jessicaBiel])
    thirdMovie._id = "third"
    realm.add([firstMovie,secondMovie,thirdMovie])
}

let allActors = realm.objects(Actor.self)
let actorWithMostMovies = allActors.max(by: {$0.actedIn.count < $1.actedIn.count})
actorWithMostMovies?.name //"Nicholas Cage"
actorWithMostMovies?.actedIn.count //3
```

Comment: Looks legit!  I'm gonna test that right now. Thanks David!

Comment: Works great! Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.